# Parameter not being passed to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 application where user accounts can be created in two ways: by new users (sign up) or by admin users (add account).

My thought process was to send all requests to the new action in the User controller, have some logic in there to see if it's a new user or an admin user and handle the request accordingly. Here's my template:

**new_by_admin.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h1 class="centertext">Add User</h1>
        <%= render 'add_user_fields', f: f %>

        <%= f.submit "Create account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

In the controller, this works fine:

**user_controller.rb:**

```
def new
    @user = User.new
    if !signed_in?
        @user.confirmation_code = User.new_confirmation_code
    elsif signed_in? && current_user.admin?
        new_by_admin
    else
        redirect_to root_url
    end
end

def new_by_admin
    @user = User.new
end
```

However, the below code throws a "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" error in the template, presumably because @user is nil.

```
def new
    @user = User.new
    if !signed_in?
        @user.confirmation_code = User.new_confirmation_code
    elsif signed_in? && current_user.admin?
        render 'new_by_admin', user: @user
    else
        redirect_to root_url
    end
end
```

What is the difference between these, and why doesn't the second method work even though I'm passing the @user object as a parameter to the partial?

Answer (score 1):

`render` allows you to instruct a contollers action to render a different view than the default that matches the action name (`new` in your case).  When the specified view is rendered it has access to any of the instance vars set by the action.  There's no need to pass anything as a param (I'm not even sure that's possible).

Instead, just use: `render :new_by_admin`

Comment: When I use render :new_by_admin, I get the same error.

Comment: Does it work if you use `User.new` instead of `@user` directly in your form?

Comment: Yes, but I read somewhere that that's not a good thing to do in general.

Comment: Reasons described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914275/ok-to-instantiate-an-object-in-the-view

Comment: Yeah, I understand those, just trying to isolate the issue.  Are there any partials being used here?  Or, is it really just a single view file named `new_by_admin.html.erb`?

Comment: I resolved it. See my answer below. Your guidance helped a lot by the way, so I upvoted you. Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. While looking at the terminal on the server, I noticed that the requests were being sent to users#new_by_admin. So it was a problem in the routes.rb file. I had the route defined like this (from earlier attempts):

```
get '/adduser', to: 'users#new_by_admin', as: 'add_user'
```

Changing this to:

```
get '/adduser', to: 'users#new, as: 'add_user'
```

Made it work. I don't fully understand why, since the user object was initiated inside the new_by_admin method as well, but it works now. I also changed the render line in the OP to the below as per stakechaser's suggestion:

```
render :new_by_admin
```

Comment: I agree with you, it seems like it should have worked without the route change.  Probably need to dig into the `form_for` code to better understand root cause.  Glad it's working now!