# Initializing a new object for a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am just learning rails and hope someone can guide me on a theory question.

The course assignment I am working on requires me to initialize a new comment object for a partial that includes a form for submitting a new comment. The form is not to be rendered if the user is not logged in to the application.

From what I know so far, you are encouraged to keep as much code as possible in the controller, so I figured that is the best place for the initialization of @comment = @post.comments.new.

Snippet from posts_controller.rb:

```
  def show
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new
    authorize @comment
    @comments = @post.comments.all    
  end
```

And here is the partial comments/_form.html.erb:

```
<h3>Add a comment:</h3>
<%= form_for [topic, post, comment], html: {class: "form-inline"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label "Body" %>
  <%= text_field(:comment, :body) %>
  <%= f.submit "Create Comment" %>
<% end %>
```

And here is the form that calls the partial post/show.html.erb:

```
<h1><%= markdown_to_html @post.title %></h1>
<div>
  <%= image_tag(@post.image.small.url) if @post.image? %>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <small>
      <%= image_tag(@post.user.avatar.tiny.url) if @post.user.avatar? %>
      submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> ago by
      <%= @post.user.name %>
    </small>
    <p><%= markdown_to_html @post.body %></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <% if policy(@post).edit? %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_post_path(@topic, @post), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <% end %>   
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <h1>Comments</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<%= render partial: "comments/comments", collection: @comments, as: :comment %>
<% if policy(Comment.new).create? %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post, comment: @comment } %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that if the user is not logged in to the application, the authorization for @comment fails in the controller, and prevents posts/show.html.erb from rendering.

Maybe I could do something like this in posts/show.html.erb ?:

```
   <% if policy(Comment.new).create? %>
    <% @comment = Comment.new %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post, comment: @comment } %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Is this legit, or is it poor technique?

Any advice to point me in the right moral direction is appreciated!

Comment: In posts/show you want to create comments object..right?

Comment: That is correct, but only if the user is logged in. I meant to include authorize @comment in my proposed coding in posts.show.

Comment: so in view you can check with a condition `if current_user`

Comment: Correct. I also just verified that new comment should be initialized in the view by using @comment = Comment.new. My basic question is if this is acceptable coding style, or should the initialization be kept in the controller.

Comment: `policy(Comment.new).create?` what this statement do?

Comment: It prohibits the partial from being rendered if the user is not logged in.

Comment: so it is as simple as `if current_user`..right?

Comment: Correct. It is essentially doing that, but using the Pundit gem's policy method.

Comment: The object would never be instantiated unless the partial was rendered because it is inside the If.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is with the `authorize @comment` line in the controller. This line caused you problems in the first place, so let's consider changing it.

Since this is the posts controller then you should authorize a post object there, not a comment object. This way you can leave the creation of the `@comment` in the controller. It goes more in line with Rails conventions anyway.

Usage of `if policy(Comment.new).create?` in the view is correct, although with this change you can now also do `if policy(@comment).create?`.

Answer (score 0):

That does look like it would work, but without seeing your policy, we can't be sure.  You could also try the following to simply check if there's a current user present, assuming you're using devise.

```
<% if current_user.present? %>
  <% @comment = Comment.new %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post, comment: @comment } %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would work for the time being, but, what if you later changed the policy for new comments? You would then have to hunt down all the places where you used <% if current_user.present? %> and fix them. It is probably better to stick with <% if policy(Comment.new).create? %> so changes could be made in one place, adhering to DRY.

My code does work. I was just wondering if the view was the proper place to instantiate objects.

I did find my answer here: [Ok to instantiate an object in the View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914275/ok-to-instantiate-an-object-in-the-view)